# Reduce $(2|b|)^{\log{\epsilon}/\log{2|b|}}$ to $\epsilon$ (Stuck in my own proof)

Tags: real-analysis

I want to show that $(2|b|)^{\log{\epsilon}/\log{2|b|}},  |b|< 1/2$ can be reduced to $\epsilon$. I have tried this in a CAS program just to make sure that my proof is correct, but I must admit (even if it is a bit embarrassing) actually can't do by hand.

I'm pretty sure that my proof is correct so I have only trouble with algebra.

Kind regards,

Comment: $\frac{\text{log} \epsilon}{\text{log} 2|b|}=\text{log}_{2|b|} {\epsilon}$.

Comment: What do you mean by "reduced to $\epsilon$? If it is $a^{\frac{\log(\epsilon)}{\log (a)}}=\epsilon$ for $a\lt1$ you are wrong.

Comment: @Piquito I do not know. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, we see that we can write:

$$x^\frac{\text{n}}{\ln\left(x\right)}=\left(x^\frac{1}{\ln\left(x\right)}\right)^\text{n}\tag1$$

Notice that we can write:

$$x=\exp\left(\ln\left(x\right)\right)\tag2$$

So:

$$x^\frac{1}{\ln\left(x\right)}=\left(\exp\left(\ln\left(x\right)\right)\right)^\frac{1}{\ln\left(x\right)}=\exp\left(\frac{1}{\ln\left(x\right)}\cdot\ln\left(x\right)\right)=\exp\left(1\right)=e^1=e\tag3$$

So concluding, when $\text{n}=\ln\left(\epsilon\right)$:

$$\exp\left(\ln\left(\epsilon\right)\right)=\epsilon\tag4$$

> Pay attention to the fact that when $\left|x\right|<\frac{1}{2}$ we have that $-\frac{1}{2}<x<\frac{1}{2}$ (in the real numbers) which means that $-1<x<1$ but when the base is negative there is a problem.

Comment: Is this also okay for $2|b| < 1 $ ?

Comment: @Xenusi Try to prove that!

Comment: I have done that. I think I'm done.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I actually did the same thing as you, but I made a mistake during the calculations and did not get $\epsilon$ and I couldn't figure out what went wrong. Thanks!

Comment: I actually think my proof only works for $\epsilon < 1$. Since it is a $\epsilon$-proof, so $\epsilon$ is a small positive value, then I guess it is alright.